# Creating a simple mobile agent system

Tags: agent

I am looking to create a simple mobile agent system which will deal with 4 tasks, i.e 4 different mobile agents jobs:  Database update, meeting scheduling, network services discovery and kernel update.

I have done my research and have seen different frameworks such as Aglet, Jade, agent builder etc.  My question is which one should i use?  Also i need to setup the base code for it to work, can someone point me to a site or help me to setup the basic functions of the mobile agent?

I've read about tahiti server for the Aglet model.  I'm quite confused about how to set up the mobile agent system.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I have also tried to it using RMI.  I had created a method of type agent, but i couldn't pass it through remote method implementation.  I was reading about tcp and udp socket programming.  I was thinking may be it would be more fair to do it using socket programming.  In this case, would this be called an agent?  I was thinking about the server sending datagram packets to multiple clients.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself why you want to use mobile agents at all. The notion of a mobile agent was popular in the agent research community in the early 90's, but fell out of favour because (i) it wasn't clear what problem it was solving, (ii) the capability to allow arbitrary code to migrate to a particular computer and execute with enough privileges to access local data and services is very open to abuse, and (iii) all of the claimed benefits of mobile agents can actually be achieved though web services (REST or otherwise) and open data formats such as RDF. Consequently, few, if any, mobile agent platforms have been properly maintained since the early experiments.

It also sounds as though you need to be clear which end-user problem you want to solve. Scheduling a meeting and updating my kernel are *very* different tasks - I'd be very uncomfortable with a program that claims do both. If your interest is in the automation of system maintenance tasks, such as DB tuning and kernel patching, on large networks you might want to look at the [SmartFrog](http://wiki.smartfrog.org/wiki/display/sf/SmartFrog+Home) project, or read up on [autonomic computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomic_computing).

Comment: Hi, It is my final year dissertation in Computer engineering.  I have chosen it because i wanted to prove that agents could be used to automate these processes.  It is a challenging project.

Comment: Hi, It is my final year dissertation in Computer engineering.  I have chosen it because i wanted to prove that agents could be used to automate these processes.  It is a challenging project. 

I have done lots of research concerning mobile agents and have realised the potential behind them.  In fact there are two types of mobile agents:  Intraplatform and interplatform mobile agents.  I have managed to create a few intraplatform agents and they are working fine under jade framework.

Comment: My problem now is interplatform mobility.  I have installed the jade interplatform mobility service and have created a few agents but i cannot migrate them.   I have edited the host files on both computers to be as follows:

Slave 1:
10.0.0.3     Slave1
10.0.0.5     Slave2

Slave 2:
10.0.0.5    Slave2
10.0.0.3    Slave1

Note that Slave1 has IP address 10.0.0.3
Slave2 has IP address 10.0.0.5

Comment: I have installed jipms & jade on both machines and they are both running through the following arguments:

Slave1:
-gui -platform-id slave1 -services jade.core.mobility.AgentMobilityService;jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobilityService

Slave2:
-gui -platform-id slave2 -services jade.core.mobility.AgentMobilityService;jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobilityService

Comment: However when i start my mobile agent i get the following error:

run:
Feb 19, 2012 3:23:15 PM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer
Retrieving CommandDispatcher for platform slave1
INFO: ----------------------------------
    This is JADE 4.1.1 - revision 6532 of 2011/11/18 16:21:34
    downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions,
    at http://jade.tilab.com/
----------------------------------------
Feb 19, 2012 3:23:18 PM jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager initialize
INFO: Listening for intra-platform commands on address:
- jicp://169.254.107.142:1099

Comment: Feb 19, 2012 3:23:19 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.management.AgentManagement initialized
Feb 19, 2012 3:23:19 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.messaging.Messaging initialized
Feb 19, 2012 3:23:19 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.resource.ResourceManagement initialized
Feb 19, 2012 3:23:19 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.mobility.AgentMobility initialized
Feb 19, 2012 3:23:19 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobility initialized
Feb 19, 2012 3:23:19 PM

Comment: properly.
Hello World. I am an agent!
My LocalName: m
My Name: m@slave1
My Address: http://Priesh-PC:7778/acc
0
1
2
3
Feb 19, 2012 3:25:59 PM jade.core.migration.MigrationInitiator handleAllResponses
WARNING: MigrationInitiator: Timeout expired.
4
Feb 19, 2012 3:25:59 PM jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobilityService$ServiceComponent handleInformMigrationResult
WARNING: Migration failure: Aborting migration: Timeout to receive migration response has expired

Comment: i cannot seem to paste my whole code here, i hope you are getting an idea about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use JADE and I agree with the first guy, agent systems usually take alot of overhead to going so if you can avoid it, please do. If however you choose to proceed choose a platform with alot of support and a big user group.

Jade has some neat features like a directory facilitator DF, which works like a yellow pages so other agents don't have to know what agents are running and what services are supplied they can simply inquire by the DF.

Also JADE ContractNetBehaviours help simplify communication.

Comment: @user1169763 After readding the comments on the previous answer I see you've chosen JADE. I think you should start a new Question for your mobility problems. Also join the JADE mailing group list.